# Serverless framework WarmUp plugin not being called

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I tried to integrate the WarmUp serverless plugin into my project. However, I believe that it is not working. I see no invocations from WarmUp in the lambda’s CloudWatch log group, and lambda does need warmup time after being idle for a bit.

My configuration is below:

```
service: ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME}):service}

provider:
  name: aws
  custom:
    roleName: ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME_STAGE}):roleName}
    profileName: ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME_STAGE}):profileName}
    bundle:
      ignorePackages:
        - pg-native
    warmup:
      enabled: true
      events:
        - schedule: rate(5 minutes)
      prewarm: true
  plugins:
    - pluginHandler
    - serverless-plugin-warmup
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action:
        - 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      Resource:
      - Fn::Join:
        - ':'
        - - arn:aws:lambda
          - Ref: AWS::Region
          - Ref: AWS::AccountId
          - function:${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-*
  cfLogs: true
  stage: ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME_STAGE}):stage}
  region: ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME_STAGE}):region}
  memorySize: ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME_STAGE}):memorySize}
  timeout: ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME_STAGE}):timeout}
  keepWarm: false
  useApigateway: true

package:
  exclude:
    ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME}):exclude}

functions:
  lambdaHandler:
    handler: ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME_STAGE}):handler}
    events:
      ${file(./${env:DEPLOY_FILE_NAME}):events}
    warmup:
      enabled: true
```

The lambda code:

```
const awsLambdaFastify = require('aws-lambda-fastify');
const app = require('./index');

const proxy = awsLambdaFastify(app);

const fastify = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  proxy(event, context, callback);
};

const warm = func => (event, context, callback) => {
  if (event.source === 'serverless-plugin-warmup') {
    return callback(null, 'Lambda is warm!');
  }

  return func(event, context, callback);
};

exports.handler = warm(fastify);
```

Is there something that I could check? Any suggestions/directions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You have `keepWarm: false`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Good looking out. Unfortunately, changing the default keepWarm to true did not help.

Comment: I see you haven't defined the Lambda payload, but it should still invoke with the default even though it'll likely error out. Have you checked in the AWS console, if the invoke event was created (every 5 minutes)?

Comment: I don't know how to check in the console, but from CloudWatch logs it is clear - there is no warm-up event. Unsure what you mean by defining the payload. Warmup wraps lambda eg. handler goes to warmup, which checks the source and reacts when the source is the warmup invocation. It is in the documentation.

Comment: you need to change events schedule to concurrency  
 warmup:
      enabled: true # Whether to warm up functions by default or not
      prewarm: true # Run WarmUp immediately after a deploymentlambda
      concurrency: 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, please move out the plugins from `provider`

```
plugins:
    - serverless-plugin-warmup
provider:
    ...
```